# No web tab on the OS X Lion Server interface

Tags: macos, webserver, server.app

I just installed Mac OS X Lion Server and it doesn't have the Web tab in the services pane. This looked like it was supposed to come standard.

How else can I access the Web part of the server?

Comment: Can you clarify where you're looking for the Web service (i.e. in Server.app, Server Admin, or the Sharing pane of System Preferences)?  What're you seeing instead of it?  Note: in Lion Server, the web service should be managed from Server.app, and should be listed under "SERVICES" in the sidebar...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using the wrong app: in Lion Server, you no longer set up web in **Server Admin**, you set it up in **Server app**.

Either this, or you are using a display with a very low resolution and the Server app window is too small to display all its services.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to refer to [Lion Server: Advanced Admininstration](http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/). You will need to use the Server.app

```
Use the Server app to start web service.
 1. In the Server app, click Web.
  * If web service has never been turned on before, select Enable Service.
  * If web service was previously turned on, the Enable Service dialog doesn’t appear.
 2. Choose On from the pop-up menu under the service name in the Web pane.
```

Comment: Thanks, but the service isn't even available to me. I cant turn it on or off.